# How do you go from List<> to class in Automapper c#

Tags: c#, automapper

In the current example I find it easy going HeaderPayload => Header since I just use the `source.Data.Values` directly.
What let's me construct the other way Header => HeaderPayload?

The current config is wrong and fails in the Map call.

```
        [Test]
        public void TestAutoMapper2()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Header, HeaderPayload>()
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.Data, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Values))
                        ;
            });

            var a = new Header { Values = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" } };

            var mapper = new Mapper(config);

            // act
            var b = mapper.Map<Header>(a);

            // assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(b.Data);
            Assert.IsNotEmpty(b.Data.Values);
            Assert.AreEqual("foo", b.Data.Values.FirstOrDefault());
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public List<string> Values { get; set; }
        }

        public class Header
        {
            public List<string> Values { get; set; }
        }

        public class HeaderPayload
        {
            public Data Data { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: You don't. AutoMapper is meant to perform very specific **direct** mappings, not act as an everything to everything mapper or LINQ's Select. A and B have nothing in common -neither member names nor types. AutoMapperr can't decide by itself that a `List<string>` should be arbitrarily converted to some other class that may have one or more properties with that type

Comment: Read [AutoMapper's Design Philosophy](https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/), especially the opening paragraph `it becomes clear to me that it's not that AutoMapper was "abused" per se, but that it was used without understanding why AutoMapper exists and what problems it was designed to solve.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand. What is the approach in this case? Drop automapper and write conversion by hand? Thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: In this case you have to explicitly create a new C from the `List<string>`. There is no mechanism in C# that would initialize a type from a subset of its property's types. You have to write a `new C{ Values=source.Values}`. Once you do that - why use AutoMapper? BTW AutoMapper does allow you to specify a custom resolver, but this is clearly not a scenario it was meant to address

Comment: What is the real problem? Why are you using AutoMapper in the first place? What are A, B and C? Other people may not have your requirements.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The real scenanario is a two way conversion. I should be able to go from A=>B and vice versa. Le's say that one class is strictly typed (A) and the other is JSONifiable (B).

Comment: To get an answer *read the Philosophy article* to decide yourself. Then read [AutoMapper Usage Guidelines](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/). Don't skip them, especially the DON'Ts, eg `X DO NOT use AutoMapper except in cases where the destination type is a flattened subset of properties of the source type` or `X AVOID using AutoMapper when you have a significant percentage of custom configuration in the form of Ignore or MapFrom` because `The "Auto" is for "automatic" and if it's not "Auto" then don't use this library, it will make things more, not less complicated.`

Comment: That's not a real scenario, that's a description of the attempted solution. Converting Orders and Items to a flat OrderItem is a real scenario. When you talk about As and Bs, it's not a real scenario

Comment: That's the issue I am trying to solve. Get JSON which is badly constructed fit into a model describing the domain. And put it in JSON once again.

Comment: There's no strictly-typed vs JSONifiable either, JSON.NET can serialize any class. From the comments it looks like you want to map your app class to a message class, but without knowing what those look like, it's impossible to say what should or shouldn't be done to map them. The question you posted is definitely *not* what AutoMapper is about - converting a complex model to a simpler model

Comment: Indeed thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for clarifying.

Comment: Explain the **actual** problem - that means post the **actual** classes. If it was easy to deduce what each one contains, AutoMapper would have worked already. Clearly, they are both complex and different. Right now, it's hard to guess which class is the domain class and which one is the message class

Comment: The structure is simmilar. I smplified the problem. Message class is B and domain class is A. Let's call them HeaderPayload.cs (message = B) and Header.cs (model = A).